# Symfony2 Override Constraints

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `BaseEntity` class:

```
class BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * The name.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=255, minMessage="default.name.short", maxMessage="default.name.long")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "default.name.not_blank")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

and

```
class UserEntity extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=255, minMessage="user.name.short", maxMessage="default.name.long")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "user.name.not_blank")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Now, When I post a new `UserEntity` into the form with long or short name Symfony gives me 2 errors: (for long:)

- default.name.long
- user.name.long

But I want it to show only ONE error, so :
 - user.name.long

e.g. I want to **override**, but do not add another one

Comment: As I know you cann't override validation defined for parent class.
The best workaround is to add validation group to your validatiors with which you will be entity validated.

Comment: Also did not find any other way

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for a validator group. So you can split up you validation rules into groups.

There is a excellent documentation about this feature:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Custom Validation Constraint could help you if you could (depending of your application logic) remove those two validations and make your own.

Something like this maybe?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to set up at least some of your validation rules via a YAML file rather than annotations, you can override the base class's validation settings without needing to edit the class file itself.

Your YAML file would look something like this and would need to be in a location like `src/YourApp/YourBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml` to be picked up automatically:

```
BaseEntity:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank:
                message: user.name.not_blank
            - Length:
                min: 2
                minMessage: user.name.short
                max: 255
                maxMessage: default.name.long
```

If you want to put your validation file in a non-standard location, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210501/328817